# assign a value to df.column iteratively after condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains a column that has a list in it. The list can either be blank or have a dictionary at its first entry.

```
   index                                   labels
    0                                                     []
    1      [{'id': 1178423440, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxMT...
    2      [{'id': 1178425127, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxMT...
    3      [{'id': 1213670757, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxMj...
    4      [{'id': 1178430857, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxMT...
```

I want to assign the value with key = 'id' in place of the list (for each entry). Here is what I have done.

```
for i in issues['labels']:
    if not i: continue
    i=i[0]['id']
```

I realize this is assigning the value because the df remains the same (even though it runs). what am I doing wrong?

expected output:

```
   index          labels
    0                                                    
    1          1178423440
    2          1178425127
    3          1213670757
    4          1178430857
```

edit:

say, if index 0 in the list within each row contained 2 or more dictionaries like so

```
 [{'id': 1497192821, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxNDk3MTkyODIx', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/chef/chef/labels/Focus:%20knife%20bootstrap', 'name': 'Focus: knife bootstrap', 'color': '92ef98', 'default': False, 'description': ''}, {'id': 1178425127, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxMTc4NDI1MTI3', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/chef/chef/labels/Platform:%20Windows', 'name': 'Platform: Windows', 'color': 'a2c429', 'default': False, 'description': ''}, 
{'id': 1178435805, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWwxMTc4NDM1ODA1', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/chef/chef/labels/Status:%20Waiting%20on%20Contributor', 'name': 'Status: Waiting on Contributor', 'color': '0052cc', 'default': False, 'description': 'A pull request that has unresolved requested actions from the author.'},
{'id': 525658991, 'node_id': 'MDU6TGFiZWw1MjU2NTg5OTE=', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/chef/chef/labels/Type:%20Bug', 'name': 'Type: Bug', 'color': 'bfe5bf', 'default': False, 'description': "Doesn't work as expected."}]
```

how can I parse all the values of key='id' and append it to the `labels` column at the same position?

expected op:

```
index     labels
0          []                                  #has no entries
1          [1178423440,1178435805,525658991]    # has 3 dictionaries with 3 different id values (values with key='id)
2          [1178425127,132131,13213]           # slly, has 2 id values
3          [1389810]                           # has one id value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` methods here for correct working if no match, then is returned `NaN`:

```
issues['labels'] = issues['labels'].str[0].str.get('id')
```

If need integers with missing values use [integer nan](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
issues['labels'] = issues['labels'].str[0].str.get('id').astype('Int64')
```

EDIT: If each dictionary has `id` use:

```
issues['labels'] = issues['labels'].apply(lambda x: [y['id'] for y in x])
```

If possible some dict has no `id` add testing:

```
issues['labels'] = issues['labels'].apply(lambda x: [y['id'] for y in x if 'id' in y])
```

Comment: Thanks @jezreal would you know the solution to the edit I just made to the issue?

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami - If there is multiple dictionaries what is expected output?

Comment: edited the issue with expected output. Thanks a lot!